# How i can generate a date field in Razor based on metadata validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a such code which i am going to validate in my view

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using ValidationProject.Models;


namespace ValidationProject.Models
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage="This is field is required")]
        public int one;

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "This is field is required")]
        public string two;

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime date;
    }
}
```

when i try to generate a datetime field in razor i get only textbox instead of date field. Razor code is given below:

```
@using ValidationProject.Models;
@model Class1
@{
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <link href="~/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("input").bind("input propertychange", function () {
                if($(this).not("field-validation-error"))
                {
                    $(this).addClass("success");

                }
            });
        });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .input-validation-error {
            border: 3px solid red;
            background-color:  #fee;
        }
        .field-validation-error{
            background:url("@Url.Content("~/Content/1.png")") no-repeat;
            font-size:15px;
            background-size:25% 100%;
            padding-left:60px;
            padding-top:15px;
            padding-bottom:15px;
            color:black;
        }
    </style>
}
@{Html.EnableClientValidation();}
@{Html.EnableUnobtrusiveJavaScript();}

 @using (@Html.BeginForm())
 {
     @Html.EditorFor(m=>m.date)
     <input type="submit" />

 }
```

There i use `@Html.EditorFor(m=>m.date)` for generate a date fieald in razor but it can't do  it.
Please help.

Comment: you need to use jquery datepicker :some links for reference
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_datepicker.htm,https://www.script-tutorials.com/datepicker-jquery-ui/

Comment: Thanks, but why it doesn't generate an <input type="date" /> ?

Comment: Because your model contains only fields - change them to properties - `public DateTime date { get; set; }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke  `new { type = "date" }`  in html attributes is needed or not?? do u have an idea

Comment: @ShashankSood, That is not necessary (unless you were using `TextBoxFor()`) - the `EditorFor()` method respects the `DataTypeAttribute` and will generate `<input type="date" .... />` but only for properties (and they need to be properties anyway otherwise model binding would not work)